# Best way for watching an RSS feed for updates?

Tags: ios, objective-c, rss

**I need to have a functionality in my app where the user gets updates from an RSS feed.**

The problem is, depending on the user there might be 10-20 or even more RSS feeds to follow. Right now I'm doing this the most simple way:

- when the app launches, get ALL feeds
- parse them (could be even 500 entries PER feed)
- look for changes by the date of each entry in the RSS.

For about 20 feeds this whole process takes maybe 10 seconds, and that isn't really acceptable.

**My question is, can I somehow optimize this process?** Can I just "peak" at an rss feed and check the number of entries, without fetching the whole feed?

```
NSURL *url = @"http://www.feedurl.com/feed";
NSString *xmlString = [NSString stringWithContentsOfURL:url encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:nil];
```

I'm doing this for each feed and then I'm using [TBXML](http://www.tbxml.co.uk/TBXML/TBXML_Free.html) to parse it. Nothing is done on the main thread of course.

Answer (score -1):

I highly recommend [MWFeedParser](https://github.com/mwaterfall/MWFeedParser)

Easy to use and fully functional

Comment: Sorry, that doesn't have anything to do with my question. I already know how to get a feed.

Comment: Im sorry, but i understood another thing,